# Access raspberry Pi without ip

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

Is there a way to reach the raspberry Pi, since the ip is dynamically assigned to each device.
I have to use the API that the raspberry Pi is serving.

Comment: Your question is very vague, and probably off-topic since StackOverflow is for programming questions only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know its IP to access, for example, via SSH. To connect to your Pi via SSH, you will need to enable SSH first. So, you will have to connect the Pi to a monitor first to enable it.
To find out its IP, you can do a *LAN neighbours scan* in your network. You can use a mobile app like [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en) or you can use a windows program like [GlassWire](https://glasswire.com).